# Convert a date from UTC timezone to PST Time zone (including DST factor)

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, to-timestamp

I want to convert a date in UTC timezone to PST timezone. The NEW_TIME doesn't take into account the DST (Daylight Saving Time) factor, so I tried using CAST and TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ functions but both gave incorrect time ( difference of around 5 hrs 30 min). Not sure why.

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(max(end_date) AT TIME ZONE 'PST')
      ,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
FROM table1
WHERE NAME= 'FIRST';
```

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(CAST((max(end_date) AT TIME ZONE 'PST') AS DATE )
      ,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
FROM table1
WHERE NAME= 'FIRST';
```

Instead of 'PST' I also tried using 'US/PACIFIC', but it too gave the same result.

max(end_date) is        : 2021-03-15 07:17:16 (in UTC)

The query is returning (incorrect time returned) : 14-MAR-2021 18:47:16

The time that it should  (correct time expected): 15-MAR-2021 00:17:16

Can anyone please help in correcting my query or any other function that can convert the date from UTC to PST time zone (keeping the DST factor in mind).

Comment: Does `end_date` have a time zone in the table or not? I.e. is it stored as `TIMESTAMP '2021-03-15 07:17:16 UTC'` in a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type or as  `TIMESTAMP '2021-03-15 07:17:16'` in a `TIMESTAMP` data type (and the time zone is not stored).

Comment: No, it does not have a time zone stored, it is just of Datatype TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 6 hours time difference, so I'm going to assume that you are in the same time zone as `Asia/Dacca` and have set up my session using:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE='Asia/Dacca';
```

Now, if I create `table1` with the data type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  name     VARCHAR2(20),
  end_date TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
);

INSERT INTO table1 ( name, end_date ) VALUES ( 'FIRST', TIMESTAMP '2021-03-15 07:17:16 UTC' );
```

Then your query (you do not need to use `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` on a column that is already a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column):

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         max(end_date) AT TIME ZONE 'PST',
         'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
       ) AS pst_end_date
FROM   table1
WHERE  NAME = 'FIRST';
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | PST_END_DATE         |
> | :------------------- |
> | 15-MAR-2021 00:17:16 |
> ```

and works!

---

However, if you store `end_date` using a `TIMESTAMP` (without time zone):

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  name     VARCHAR2(20),
  end_date TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO table1 ( name, end_date ) VALUES ( 'FIRST', TIMESTAMP '2021-03-15 07:17:16' );
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         max(end_date) AT TIME ZONE 'PST',
         'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
       ) AS pst_end_date
FROM   table1
WHERE  NAME = 'FIRST';
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | PST_END_DATE         |
> | :------------------- |
> | 14-MAR-2021 18:17:16 |
> ```

Which replicates your issue.

This is because the database does not know the time zone of the data and will implicitly assume that it is the same as the database/session time zone and we've set that to `Asia/Dacca` and not `UTC`. Instead we need to explicitly tell the database to use the `UTC` time zone for the conversion:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         FROM_TZ(max(end_date), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'PST',
         'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
       ) AS pst_end_date
FROM   table1
WHERE  NAME = 'FIRST';
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | PST_END_DATE         |
> | :------------------- |
> | 15-MAR-2021 00:17:16 |
> ```

---

If your column has the `DATE` data type:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  name     VARCHAR2(20),
  end_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO table1 ( name, end_date ) VALUES ( 'FIRST', TIMESTAMP '2021-03-15 07:17:16' );
```

Then you can use the same query with an added `CAST`:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         FROM_TZ(CAST(max(end_date) AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'PST',
         'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
       ) AS pst_end_date
FROM   table1
WHERE  NAME = 'FIRST';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=590b8ecb9957363aba5faddb4cfcf355)*